# macro to delete rows between named ranges in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How do I delete all rows between named ranges?

I have a scenario below

Name Range 1 : SUBHEADER_001 (A1:E1). Displays Headers
Name Range 2 : SUBFOOTER_001 (A40:E40). Displays legends and dates.

Between these ranges I am inserting data from sql server. The cell ranges of the SUBFOOTER_001 will change depending on the database records inserted.

I would like to know how to delete these database values between named ranges SUBHEADER_001 and SUBFOOTER_001 . Thank you.

I have googled regarding this but came across the below code snippet which will delete all rows below the range.

```
Rows(Range("MYRANGE").Cells(Range("MYRANGE").Rows.Count, 1).Row + 1 & ":65536").Delete
```

Comment: What you mean with "between", you want to delete all the cells in the range A2:E39?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you found deletes all rows down to the last row in versions before Excel 2007 (65536 rows)

you want to only delete rows to where the Footer range is.

You could replace the `65536` with your range:

```
dim iStartRow as integer
dim iEndRow as integer

iStartRow =range("SUBHEADER_001").row+1
iEndRow = range("SUBFOOTER_001").row-1

Rows(iStartRow & ":" & iEndRow).Delete
```

of course, if you don't want to delete the rows, you could also use `ClearContents`